# Python2.7 GAE Stripe Errors on LocalDevServer on os.environ['PATH']

Tags: python, google-app-engine, stripe-payments

I'm starting to upgrade my stripe payments integration to be SCA compliant. I am using Python2.7 on Google's App Engine.  I'm using a windows computer.  I've upgraded and updated the software (gcloud SDK on Windows, stripe library using pip install).

### The Error

I am trying to set things up on my local dev server so I can set things up before uploading to the Google servers to host.

When I import stripe using:

```
import stripe
```

I get an error with traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_apps\payments\payments-sca.py", line 6, in <module>
    from stripe import util
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\stripe\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from stripe.api_resources import *  # noqa
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\stripe\api_resources\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from stripe.api_resources.list_object import ListObject
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\stripe\api_resources\list_object.py", line 4, in <module>
    from stripe.stripe_object import StripeObject
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\stripe\stripe_object.py", line 8, in <module>
    from stripe import api_requestor, util, six
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\stripe\api_requestor.py", line 12, in <module>
    from stripe import error, oauth_error, http_client, version, util, six
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\stripe\http_client.py", line 32, in <module>
    import requests
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\requests\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\cryptography\x509\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\cryptography\x509\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 14, in <module>
    from asn1crypto.keys import PublicKeyInfo
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\asn1crypto\keys.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ._elliptic_curve import (
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\asn1crypto\_elliptic_curve.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ._int import inverse_mod
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\asn1crypto\_int.py", line 56, in <module>
    from ._perf._big_num_ctypes import libcrypto
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_libs\asn1crypto\_perf\_big_num_ctypes.py", line 35, in <module>
    libcrypto_path = find_library(b'crypto' if sys.version_info < (3,) else 'crypto')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\util.py", line 52, in find_library
    for directory in os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep):
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\request_environment.py", line 126, in __getitem__
    return self._request.environ[key]
KeyError: 'PATH'
```

Which looks like it is importing a whole cascade of libraries, but erroring on os.environ['PATH'] saying 'PATH' is not a key.

### Trying To Figure it Out

(1) If I directly call os.environ['PATH'] from a standard python command line shell, all is good.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PATH']
'C:\\Program Files (x86).. etc.'
```

(2) However trying to call the os.environ['PATH'] from within my GAE dev server instance causes the same bug as when trying to import stripe.  For example the simple code in one my handlers:

```
tmp=os.environ['PATH']
```

Errors with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_apps\payments\payments-sca.py", line 45, in get
    response = self.get_RegenerateResponse() # actually generate full response from datastore
  File "{_dir1_}\{_dir2_}\python_apps\payments\payments-sca.py", line 28, in get_RegenerateResponse
    tmp=os.environ['PATH'] ##############
  File "{_dir1_}\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\request_environment.py", line 126, in __getitem__
    return self._request.environ[key]
KeyError: 'PATH'
```

Implying to me that maybe we cannot call os.environ['PATH'] on the GAE dev server, but don't know why.

(3) However, once I have uploaded my code into the GAE servers then this line still errors: "tmp=os.environ['PATH']" but "import stripe" works fine with no errors.

### Question

How do I resolve this? Is there some other setup in GAE config or yaml files that I need to allow me to do this on my local dev server?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that I needed to force the environment variables in the devserver os.environ method.

Either use the following when you start the dev server

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml --env_var PATH="{{ PATH environment variable }}"
```

Or you can declare the environment variables explicitly in your app.yaml too!

I simply just put the standard response from os.environ('PATH') into these options above.